# How to check if NSMutableSet contains an element without nil error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift (and iOS programming), and I'm struggling with properly finding whether certain data structures contain elements.
More specifically, I have created an empty set into which I want to insert elements after further calculations:

```
var moviesInItinerary : NSMutableSet? = nil
```

Then, I want to proceed with the calculations only if the set is empty or if it doesn't contain a given element.
I wrote this condition like this:

```
if((moviesInItinerary?.count == 0) || (!moviesInItinerary!.containsObject(movies[currentMovie.row].title)))
```

However, when I try to run this code, I'm getting this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What is the safe way to perform these checks?

Comment: Do you really need `moviesInItinerary` to be possibly nil? From the few snippets, it seems to me that `let moviesInItinerary = NSMutableSet()` would work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You should read up on Swift's optional types. Going in blindly without understanding them is bound to lead to programming errors.

```
var moviesInItinerary : NSMutableSet? = nil
```

I'd change that to this:

```
var moviesInItinerary : NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet()
```

Then, moviesInItinerary *cannot be nil*. If you really want it to be an optional type (meaning it can possibly be nil), then change your condition to the following:

```
if let moviesSet = moviesInItineraray? {
    // use moviesSet in here. It will not be nil.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
if !(moviesInItinerary?.containsObject(movies[currentMovie.row].title) == true) {
    // When we get here, we know either moviesInItinerary is nil, or the NSMutableSet
    // does not contain our movie.
}
```

This works because optional chaining makes `moviesinItinerary?.constainsObject(movies[currentMovie.row].title)` return a value of type `Bool?`.  If it is `nil` because `moviesInItinerary` is nil, then it won't compare to `true`.  If `moviesInItinerary` isn't `nil`, then `containsObject` will either return `true` or `false` and then the comparison with work if it is `true`.  It is unnecessary to also check if `count` is `zero`, because that is redundant.  A set with `count` zero will obviously not contain your object.

Answer (score 1):

Typing `moviesInItinerary` as `NSMutableSet?` means that `NSMutableSet` can be nil, and it appears that you never assign an object to it.

This line here:

```
var moviesInItinerary : NSMutableSet? = nil
```

declares that `moviesInItinerary` itself is *either* an `NSMutableSet`, or `nil` (and in this specific case, since you never assign it anything other than `nil`, it stays like that).

Swift encourages people to use immutable variables and to avoid nullable variables whenever it makes sense to. If you always need `moviesInItinerary` to be a valid set, and you don't need to overwrite it with a different set, the best way to declare it would be:

```
let moviesInItinerary = NSMutableSet()
```

From the right-hand side of the assignment, Swift knows that the type of `moviesInItinerary` should be `NSMutableSet`, so there's no need to explicitly type it. It also knows that it cannot be `nil`, and that it cannot point to a different object after its initialization.

Since it can't be `nil`, you also no longer need to use the `.?` operator for it: just `.` will be enough.